# Regex on a number that varies in size

Tags: regex

I have a federal tax id (integer 9)(non-negative), that needs to be formatted as such 99-9999999.
In the database we have some data that doesn't fit that format so I need the regex to accommodate that data.

Value should appear as

```
1 => 1 
12 => 12 
123 => 12-3 
123456 => 12-3456
123456789 => 12-3456789
```

I also need it to not allow more than 9 numbers... and if the user enters 9 numbers I would like the regex to embed the '-' where needed.

This is what I tried.

```
[\d]{1,2}(-([\d]{0,7})?)?+$
```

But it allows 12- ('-' is only needed when more than 2 numbers

And it allows 12-34567890 (more than 9 numbers)

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just a regexp replacement. There's no way to make the addition of the `-` dependent on the length of the input.

Comment: You need `^` at the beginning, otherwise it will match 2 numbers anywhere in the data.

Comment: What is wrong with `^(\d\d)(\d{1,7})$`? See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/55rhJo/2

Comment: @revo angularjs

Comment: @revo That will allow more than 9 digits and doesn't allow hyphen.

Comment: Are trying to validate or insert `-` where needed?

Comment: @revo both? allow the user to type in 9 numbers and add the dash, or type 1 number and not add the dash

Comment: Okay so you need to go with two tasks. I added an answer with a sample code you may check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to `test()` each input string then do a `replace()` to re-format it. `test()` will use the below regular expression:

```
^\d(\d(-?\d{1,7})?)?$
```

which matches a number consisting of 1 to 9 digits with a proper match for `-` (if exists) and `replace()` will have the below one:

```
^(\d\d)-?(\d{1,7})$
```

as we need to insert `-` if we have more than 2 digits.

Demo:

```js
var numbers = ['1-', '11', '12', '123', '123456', '123456789', '12-33']
numbers.forEach(function(n) {
    if (/^\d(\d(-?\d{1,7})?)?$/.test(n)) {
        console.log(n + ' => ' + n.replace(/^(\d\d)-?(\d{1,7})$/, '$1-$2'));
    } else {
        console.log(n + ' => Wrong format.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do the whole thing in two steps: validate first, then format it.

To validate it, just match against `^\d$|^\d{2}(?:-\d{1,7})?$`. If it doesn't match, it's not valid.

To format it, use the regex `^(\d{2})(\d{1,7})$` and replace with `$1-$2`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlL2Mj/1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor it with `^` at the beginning. Otherwise, if you give it a number longer than 9 digits, it will match the last 9 digits of it.

Get rid of `+` at the end, since that allows the `-<7 digits>` to be repeated.

You need to put `?` immediately after `-` to make the hyphen optional. Your regexp makes the whole `-<7 digits>` part optional, but not the hyphen itself.

There's no need for `?` after something with a `{0,7}` quantifier, since the `0` in there makes it optional.

You don't need to put `\d` inside `[]`.

```
^\d{1,2}-?\d{0,7}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/XuYqOv/1)

I don't think you can use a simple regexp replacement function to reformat it. A static replacement string can't add the `-` after the second digit conditionally on whether the number is longer than 2 digits. If you're using a language like JavaScript or PHP, which allows using a function to calculate the replacement, you can put the conditional in there.

Answer (score 0):

[All in one solution](https://regex101.com/r/aqVD6w/3)

Regex:
`^(\d{2})-?(\d{1,7})$`

Replace:
`$1-$2`

Explanation:
by replacing the entire match with capture groups, I can capture the first 2 digits, allow the next char to be `-` but don't capture, then capture next 7 digits and invalidate anything bigger than that. Then I replace the entire match with both capture groups and stick the `-` in between.

personally, I recommend going with one of the other two step answers to this question. I just wanted to show that a one step is possible